# Playing programmatically-generated sounds on Windows with C++

Tags: c++, audio, text-to-speech

I am having the hardest time trying to find information on how to programmatically, dynamically generate audio output on Windows with C++. For example, inputting values to control pitch and tone, amplitude, etc. I would imagine that this has to be low level and closer to hardware. I am trying to make a text-to-speech program on my own. Any information is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, most audio these days is just playing a buffer of audio samples.  Those audio samples can be generated in software.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Buy a copy of Charles Pretzold's book, or find a tute that duplicates the code given in it. He demos code that does _precisely_ this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that as you seem to be new at this you should take a look at Juce library.
It should helps you to create a basic app to make audio, and then you can connect to the audio card directly
Look into the examples of the lib.
http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php

You will see that in order to get sound you have to connect to the audio system WASAPI or direct X on Win.
I really think you should use this library in order to focus on making the audio and not bothering how to connect to the audio device.
If ever you still want to do it yourself look at the wasapi api.

best

Answer (score 0):

To generate a sine wave:

**y(t) = A sin (2  Π  f  t + Φ)**

Where:
**A = Amplitude**
Π = pi (3.14159...)
**f = frequency (Hz)**
t = period (in seconds)
**Φ = phase (in radians)**

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave